# Request to Remove Tags

Tags: support

I would like to know that Where should I request or flag to remove / do spell change request for Tags?

There is one tag whose spelling is wrong: `[shareoint]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to just retag the question(s) using the wrongly spelled tag.

When no questions are using a specific tag it will automatically be deleted

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have re-tagged that question.